# Can't validate all the multilingual fields in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, multilingual, cakephp-2.1, translate

Hope all are doing well.

I need your help dear friends as I stuck to one issue in cakePHP right now as below:

Actually I have used "TranslateBehavior" of cakePHP properly for multilingual support in my site, and hopefully it worked well since now.

But the issue that I am facing now is validation of all multi-language fields.

As I have multiple fields in my view file(Form), per language.

and as and when I save the data it saves it perfectly and retrieves exactly too. based on the current language. But while inserting the data in all languages that I have used, It validates only the default language field, and omits the rest.

Please provide your views on this to guide me through.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use this plugin [cakephp-MultiTranslateBehavior](https://github.com/zoghal/cakephp-MultiTranslateBehavior)